# bottle vs cherry decision for a REST service

Tags: python, rest, cherrypy, bottle

I am putting together a REST service that can do the following:

1. Accept incoming files as part of a PUT request. The files can be as much as a few gigs in size.
2. Handle authentication.

I started my code with bottle and it was pretty compact to use but someone pointed me to cherry. I am still new to python web frameworks so would like to know people's opinions.

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask... try to be more specific than asking for general opinions.

Comment: This is the exact question I have unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, you can do RESTful webservices with any framework you like. I do have a small preference over `bottle.py`, because I like the plugins and routes as decorator model... And btw, you can put [cherry in a bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend) :-) (sorry for the joke)

But what's important given your constraints is that you do **not** use a wsgi backend to serve your files, as current wsgi implementation is a terrible bottleneck for concurrency, but instead choose [another backend](http://bottlepy.org/docs/stable/deployment.html#switching-the-server-backend).